# random subdomain with mod rewrite apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a script made in codeigniter and i need some help with it, i want my website to work on any subdomain but im not able to do'it i think it is mod_rewrite
right now if i access anysubdomain.domain.com it takes me to the index page, everything is ok but when i try to access anysubdomain.domain.com/link i get error
can anyone tell me how to modify my .htaccess file to work on anysubdomains please?

Here is the current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Page not found is the error i get